# orderBy in pivot table with relationship Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to get data get based on orderBy('fee', DESC) from pivot table in laravel.
The condition is

```
Doctor::with('doctor_hospital_settings')
->when(request('sort-by') == 'highest-fee', function ($query) {
   $query->whereHas('doctor_hospital_settings', function (Builder $query1){
      $query1->orderBy('doctor_hospital_settings.fee', 'DESC');
   })
})
->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
```

this(whereHas) runs the sub-query which does not sort the data according to Fee DESC.
It only sort data based on doctor id mentioned at the end.

```
orderBy('id', 'ASC').
```

The orderby is done in the subquery but i need this sort in main query not in subquery

**Doctor Model**

```
public function doctor_hospital_settings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Hospital::class, 'doctor_hospitals')->withPivot('fee');
}
```

How I can achieve this

Comment: CAST fee AS UNSIGNED in database

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort by a relationship using the query builder directly. This is because Laravel performs two queries. One to fetch the doctor_hospital_settings and one to fetch the fees. The fees itself are sorted, but after that they are connected to the doctor_hospital_settings which doesn't result in the same order anymore.

You have two options to make this work. The first one is using a join the second one is sorting the data based on the results you get back using the collection methods. It depends on the amount of data you get back. If you only get a view records back, the collections approach is the simplest. If you have a lot of data, the join is a better approach

Joins: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins

Collections: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections

Comment: when I used joins, it returned all the columns from three tables with repeated rows of Doctor Model. It returned all columns from Doctor, Hospital and Pivot table  which I don't need. I only need few columns from Doctor model with sorting. How I can do it by joins please add more in your answer

Comment: use `->select()` in Your query to fetch the specific columns

Comment: It Not a good approach to ask someone to write code for you since we are not aware about your schemas and relationships but.. you can add the code which you have tried so far in the question (which used Joins). so that we can help you based on that